# How to detect that user has scrolled to the bottom of the page in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I've found a number of solutions here to detect if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page, but I'm not sure how to apply them to Meteor.

I thought perhaps I should put them into the Template.someName.events callback, but I don't see any eventtype that I could use.  Is this the wrong idea?  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ordinary javascript (or jQuery). For example, you could just get the height of the current page, the height of the users window and scroll position and voila: you know if the user is at the bottom or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the code into Meteor.startup on the client that way you bypass meteor template events.

I'm using something like this on the client side (make sure to add the meteor jquery package)

```
Meteor.startup( function (){
  $('#goAllTheWayDown').bind('click', function (event){
    var h = $('html, body);
    h.animate({scrollTop: h.height()}, 1000);
  });
```

Cheers!